# Getting "Error on page" error in internet explorer 7

Tags: javascript, c#, infragistics

I have created a page in javascript and in it I created an Infragistics Grid control in which I can display the data for a search criteria. The C# code is working fine. It is reading the data from the database but not displaying the results on the web page. The page loads with a yellow mark at the corner saying "Error on page". what to do? is it a code issue or browser problem. How can I fix it? Please help.

Comment: Refer to this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308260)

Answer (score 0):

You should see the error details. these should be a Detail button on the error message popup window.

Comment: yes i open the error popup.. it says "object expected" and gave a line no where the error is coming. but i couldnt find the reason behind that.. for different search, its showing me different line no on the same source code but same error "object expected"

Comment: Okay try to attach debugger in IE. and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

- open up f12 window set start debubbing to on and see where the error occurs
- or you can right click your page on the browser and view source and goto line 200 and see if you can find any js code.

i suggest you do debug in f12 and see if you find any error

Comment: yes i open the error popup.. it says "object expected" and gave a line no where the error is coming. but i couldnt find the reason behind that.. for different search, its showing me different line no on the same source code but same error "object expected"

Comment: try to attach a debugger and see where exactly you get the error

Comment: I debug the java script but did not find any error there.. what to do?